# Extra actions in a setter of a hibernate entity

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm working on a legacy project with hibernate.  Occasionally I find code where the developers wrote extra code in the set methods of entity objects.  I'm wondering if this is an accepted practice ?  Shouldn't hibernate entity objects just be pojo classes with extra annotations and maybe a few @Transient helper methods ?

If you want to do extra actions isn't that the responsibility of the service/dao working with the entity ?

What is the best practice ?  Does anyone know of a blog or recognized article explaining this ?

Comment: Both approaches are correct, IMHO. Search for anemic model vs ddd

Comment: Well I did read follwing wiki entries

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anemic_domain_model
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design

Concepts I did know of already, but I'm still wondering in a hibernate specific case, what the best approach is.  After reading this wiki , I would have to admit that writing logic in an entity is the true OO way.  But why have a business logic layer with services if you write everything in your domain layer ?

Comment: HIbernate is quite flexible; it lets you took either approach you want. Performance won't depend on this decision, but on queries, fetching strategies for entities, chosen algorthms, I/O, parallel execution, etc. If you go by DDD, the entities are in the business layer, while Hibernate itself (Session, SessionFactory and the whole ORM) would be part of the persistence layer.

Comment: I can live with this, just wished for this project they picked either DDD or Anemic, cause now it's actually a mix of both "ideologies".  If you could post this as an answer to the question, I could mark this question as answered and close it.

Comment: Just posted an answer. Let me know if you need further clarifications, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO, both approaches are correct. They both have its pros and cons. This is related to the everlasting [Anemic model vs DDD (Domain-driven design)](http://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/AnemicDomainModel.html) war.

Regarding Hibernate, it is quite flexible. It lets you took either approach you want. Performance and correctness of the solution don't depend on the decision you take, but on the correctness of the queries, database indexes, fetching strategies for entities, chosen algorithms, I/O handling, concurrency implementation, transaction management, etc.

If you go by DDD, the entities would be part of the business layer, while Hibernate itself (Session, SessionFactory and the whole ORM) would be part of the persistence layer. In this case, the entities would contain annotations related to persistence, which would be just *hints* for the ORM.

You should also be careful with transaction management. This is better accomplished outside of the entities. (Actually, one main advantage of the anemic model is that transaction management is very easy, because you wrap every service method of your business layer inside a transactional unit).

As you've mentioned you have a mix of both "ideologies", maybe you could use that fact as an advantage: let service methods delegate the logic to domain entities, but keep transaction management in your business services.